# C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits

This should be self explanatory.  I'm trying to implement a distribution sort, and the MSVC compiler is crashing.  It seems to be a specific case to do with my SFINAE to detect a member function, this doesn't appear to happen if I don't pass indexert to a function, nor if I replace has_get_index.  It also doesn't happen if I remove either of the remaining indexer overloads.  The problem does remain if sortable has a `getIndex() const` member.

```
1>test.cpp(34): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1420)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
```

(There are no "locations listed above")  A minimal test case is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

#ifndef HAS_MEM_FUNC //SFINAE (or maybe it is?)
#define HAS_MEM_FUNC(name, func)                                        \
    template<typename T>                                                \
    struct name {                                                       \
        typedef char yes[1];                                            \
        typedef char no [2];                                            \
        template <typename C> static yes& test( typename C::func ) ;    \
        template <typename C> static no&  test(...);                    \
        static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);    \
    }
#endif
HAS_MEM_FUNC(has_get_index,getIndex);

//default indexer undefined
template <class T>
double indexer(...);
//indexer for objects that have a "T::getIndex() const" member
template <class T>
double indexer(const typename std::enable_if<has_get_index<T>::value,T>::type& b) {
    return b.getIndex();
};

template<class indexert> 
void function(indexert indexeri)
{}

struct sortable {};

int main () {
    function(indexer<sortable>); //line 34
}
```

Comment: Try filing a bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: Hm, not sure about your error, but the [pretty printer](http://louisdx.github.com/cxx-prettyprint/) has a SFINAE trait for both member types and member functions, you could take a look at that.

Comment: @Kerrek the pretty printer code claims "SFINAE type trait to detect whether "T::const_iterator T::begin/end() const" exist", but it actually checks for any member called "begin" and "end". not specifically a function... It appears the guy that coded that lib partly copied some stackoverflow answers together, without understanding how they work.

Comment: Hehe, thanks :-) The intention was for the begin/end check to actually check if the functions have the correct return type, too, but maybe that got lost somewhere on the way. Let me recheck that..

Comment: @Johannes: I made a [separate typetrait](http://pastebin.com/yK8nEjU4) to verify the type of the begin/end members. It's working for simple examples and counter-examples now, though it doesn't work for the full ppdemo.cpp yet. I'll update the pretty printer once it's fully tested. Thanks for pointing out this omission!

Comment: @Johannes: The pretty printer type trait has now been improved and should check for the precise type of the `begin`/`end` member functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably isn't what you intended:

```
template <typename C> static yes& test( typename C::func ) ;
```

With  `typename` you tell the compiler that `C::func` will be a type. In reality it will be a function, and putting a function name there in the parameter declaration doesn't make any sense.

Did you maybe intend to use `typeof` instead of `typename`?

Comment: Well that stops the compiler from crashing.  Boo Microsoft!